# Office UI Fabric React - Dropdown not respecting selectedKey prop

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I have this code:

```
<Dropdown
      selectedKey={someKeyInState}
      onChange={(e,option) => {
         // check if the dropdown should be updated
        if(someCondition){
           // update selected key
        }
        else {
           // don't update selected key
        }
      }}
      options={someOptions}
/>
```

I want to block updating the selected key if a certain condition is met. 
But, Dropdown visually shows the option that I clicked on as selected. 
How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: show your someOptions?

Comment: It's of this type IDropdownOption[], just a basic options array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my state for `selectedKey` was `undefined` it nothing is selected. When you pass in `undefined` you're basically saying to fabric to control the `selectedKey` state on it's own. 
 I fixed by passing `null` instead of `undefined`. That made the Dropdown fully controlled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react, you should not do in this way. Use a global state `optionState` and try to use conditional checks which state should be shown to use onChange method is triggered. In order to do this. First extract your conditional check to separate function.

```
myFunction = () => {
   // do conditional check and setState for optionState
}
--------------------------
onChange={myFunction}
```

Then when you select pop the key and value from the option state and update to the selectedState, now react automatically update the state and UI